# How to add style -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased to html element by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

```
var inputArkose = document.createElement('input');
inputArkose.id = "fc-token";


inputArkose.style.-webkit-font-smoothing = "antialiased"; // I need to modify this line to add css "-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased" in input element by js.

document.body.appendChild(inputArkose);
```

I want input tag to be something like this,

```
<input id="fc-token" style="-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased"></input>
```

How can I get this by javascript?

Comment: Just a guess... inputArkose.style["-webkit-font-smoothing"]

Comment: I've never done that one before so if it works good show, it should tho?